# Find closest number from uniform grid

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an integer positive number `n`. Let's say `n=5` for example. If we look at multiplies of `n`, we see these numbers (let's call it n-grid) [... -15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, ...]. Now I need to write a function `F(n, N)` that, given an integer `N`, outputs a closest number from that n-grid. For instance, `F(n, 0) = 0` (for any n). `F(5, 4) = 5`, `F(5, 7) = 5`, `F(5, 8) = 10`, `F(5, -13) = -15` and so on.

I've written this function:

```
int const x = ((::abs(N) + (n / 2)) / n) * n;
if (N > 0)
{
    return x;
}
else
{
    return -x;
}
```

It seems to work but don't like how it looks. Can anybody suggest any improvement?

Comment: What is the result of F(4,2)? I.e. does this rounding method round up or down? And what about F(4,-2)? Does it round up or away from zero?

Comment: If you are only looking to improve looks which ought to be a matter of taste. You could change to:

    int const x = (N>0?1:-1)*(::abs(N) + (n / 2)) / n) * n;

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly get rid of the `if` statement by multiplying x by `(N/abs(N))` and returning the calculated value immeadiatelly, without even saving it in `x`.

I would not do this however, because it would harm readability.

Answer (score 0):

This might be simple to understand and to look even,

```
int grid(int n, int N){
   if (N == 0) return N; 
   return n * (N > 0 ? (n + N)/n : (n + abs(N))/n );
}
```

Here is the [ideone](http://ideone.com/526rwk) result.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple math solution :-

```
F(k,x) = (x/k)*k      if  abs(x-(x/k)*k) <= k/2


       = (x/k)*k + sign(x)*k    otherwise
```

**C Implementation :-**

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<math.h>

int func(int k,int x) {

 int a = (x/k)*k; 
 int sign = x/abs(x); 

  if(abs(x-a)<=k/2) 
     return(a); 

  else return(a+sign*k); 

}

int main() {

 printf("%d",func(5,121));
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let k = 5, x = 6. abs(6-6/5)<=5/2 so your formula gives F(5,6) = 6/5 = 1 that is wrong because correct answer is 5.

Comment: Let k = 5, x = 121. abs(121-121/5)=abs(121-24) > 5/2. And your formula gives (121/5)*5 + sign(121)*5 = 125 that's wrong. Correct answer is 120.

Comment: @Nick sorry again forgot multiplying k inside the inequality. check my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
int closest_number(int n,int N)
{
    if(N==0)
        return N;
    else if(N > 0)
    {
       int temp = N % n;
       if(temp > (n/2))
           return (n*((N/n)+1));
       else
           return (n*(N/n));
    }
    else
    {
        int temp = N % n;
        if(abs(temp) > (n/2))
            return (n*((N/n)-1));
        else
            return (n*(N/n));
    }
}
```

You can find the ideone output for the given set of test cases here http://ideone.com/NlJiPt

Answer (score 0):

**You are describing a rounding algorithm**; you need to specify whether rounding is symmetric or not, and then whether it is up or down (or toward/away from zero for symmetric). [ideone demo](https://ideone.com/fork/FXQ9u1) for below code.

```
                                                       // F(4, 6)    F(4, -6)
int symmetricTowardZero(int n, int N) {
    return n * (int)(N / n);                           //    4         -4
}

int symmetricAwayFromZero(int n, int N) {
    return n * (int)(N / n + (N < 0 ? -0.5 : +0.5));   //    8         -8
}

int unsymmetricDownward(int n, int N) {
    return n * floor((double)N / n);                   //    4         -8
}

int unsymmetricUpward(int n, int N) {
    return n * ceil((double)N / n);                    //    8         -4
}
```